# php5.5 to php5.6 use syntax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

see I have these code on my previous **php5.5** code

```
<?php
use \ReflectionClass;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
/**
* 
*/
class BaseModel extends Eloquent
{
...
```

which runs fine without warnings, however running it on **php5.6**
gives me a warning, and my php artisan command doesn't like it.

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"The use statement with non-compound name 'ReflectionClass' has no effect","file":"\/home\/vagrant\/myproject\/app\/models\/BaseModel.php","line":2}}
```

My question is, do i completely remove it?, removing it solves the problem, is there any side effect on that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can remove it, if it's already in the global namespace there is no need to add a `use` statement unless you plan to alias it, i.e.`use \ReflectionClass as RC;`

Comment: Thanks for your help.